# Web Scraping & BeautifulSoup <li> parsing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm just learning web **scraping** & want to output the result of this website to a csv file
https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets

but am struggling with year, sn & time field in the below code -
when I put "soup" in place of "post" it works but not when I want to put them together
any help would be much appreciated

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets'

page = requests.get(url)
page

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
soup

df = pd.DataFrame({'Plane':[''], 'Year':[''], 'S/N':[''], 'Total Time':[''], 'Price':[''], 'Location':[''], 'Description':[''], 'Tag':[''], 'Last updated':[''], 'Link':['']})

while True:
    
    postings = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'listing-item premium')
    for post in postings:
        try:
            link = post.find('a', class_ = 'more-info').get('href')
            link_full = 'https://www.avbuyer.com'+ link
            plane = post.find('h2', class_ = 'item-title').text
            price = post.find('div', class_ = 'price').text
            location = post.find('div', class_ = 'list-item-location').text
            year = post.find_all('ul', class_ = 'fa-no-bullet clearfix')[2]
            year.find_all('li')[0].text
            sn = post.find('ul', class_ = 'fa-no-bullet clearfix')[2]
            sn.find('li')[1].text
            time = post.find('ul', class_ = 'fa-no-bullet clearfix')[2]
            time.find('li')[2].text
            desc = post.find('div', classs_ = 'list-item-para').text
            tag = post.find('div', class_ = 'list-viewing-date').text
            updated = post.find('div', class_ = 'list-update').text
            df = df.append({'Plane':plane, 'Year':year, 'S/N':sn, 'Total Time':time, 'Price':price, 'Location':location,
                            'Description':desc, 'Tag':tag, 'Last updated':updated, 'Link':link_full}, ignore_index = True)
       
        
        except:
            pass
        
                          
        
    next_page = soup.find('a', {'rel':'next'}).get('href')
    next_page_full = 'https://www.avbuyer.com'+next_page
    next_page_full

    url = next_page_full
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')  

df.to_csv('/Users/xxx/avbuyer.csv')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get('https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
postings = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'listing-item premium')
temp=[]
for post in postings:
    link = post.find('a', class_ = 'more-info').get('href')
    link_full = 'https://www.avbuyer.com'+ link
    plane = post.find('h2', class_ = 'item-title').text
    price = post.find('div', class_ = 'price').text
    location = post.find('div', class_ = 'list-item-location').text
    t=post.find_all('div',class_='list-other-dtl')
    for i in t:
        data=[tup.text for tup in i.find_all('li')]
        years=data[0]
        s=data[1]
        total_time=data[2]

        temp.append([plane,price,location,link_full,years,s,total_time])

df=pd.DataFrame(temp,columns=["plane","price","location","link","Years","S/N","Totaltime"])
print(df)
```

output:

```
                         plane                  price                                           location                                               link      Years           S/N           Totaltime
0     Dassault Falcon 2000LXS              Make offer  North America + Canada, United States - MD, Fo...  https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/...  Year 2021       S/N 377       Total Time 33
1        Cirrus Vision SF50 G1           Please call   North America + Canada, United States - WI, Fo...  https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/...  Year 2018      S/N 0080      Total Time 615
2               Gulfstream IV              Make offer  North America + Canada, United States - MD, Fo...  https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/...  Year 1990      S/N 1148     Total Time 6425
4                Boeing 787-8              Make offer      Europe, Monaco, For Sale by Global Jet Monaco  https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/...  Year 2010         S/N -        Total Time 1
5                 Hawker 4000              Make offer      South America, Puerto Rico, For Sale by JetHQ  https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/...  Year 2009     S/N RC-24     Total Time 2120
6          Embraer Legacy 500              Make offer  North America + Canada, United States - NE, Fo...  https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/...  Year 2015  S/N 55000016     Total Time 2607
7     Dassault Falcon 2000LXS              Make offer  North America + Canada, United States - DE, Fo...  https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/...  Year 2015       S/N 300     Total Time 1909
8        Dassault Falcon 50EX            Please call   North America + Canada, United States - TX, Fo...  https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/...  Year 2002       S/N 320   Total Time 7091.9
9        Dassault Falcon 2000              Make offer  North America + Canada, United States - MD, Fo...  https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/...  Year 2001       S/N 146     Total Time 6760
10      Bombardier Learjet 75              Make offer          Europe, Switzerland, For Sale by Jetcraft  https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/...  Year 2014    S/N 45-491     Total Time 1611
11                Hawker 800B            Please call   Europe, United Kingdom - England, For Sale by ...  https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/...  Year 1985    S/N 258037     Total Time 9621
13             BAe Avro RJ100            Please call   North America + Canada, United States - MT, Fo...  https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/...  Year 1996     S/N E3282    Total Time 45996
14         Embraer Legacy 600              Make offer  North America + Canada, United States - MD, Fo...  https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/...  Year 2007  S/N 14501014     Total Time 4328
15  Bombardier Challenger 850              Make offer  North America + Canada, United States - AZ, Fo...  https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/...  Year 2003      S/N 7755  Total Time 12114.1
16            Gulfstream G650            Please call           Europe, Switzerland, For Sale by Jetcraft  https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/...  Year 2013      S/N 6047     Total Time 2178
17      Bombardier Learjet 55     Price: USD $995,000  North America + Canada, United States - MD, Fo...  https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/...  Year 1982       S/N 020    Total Time 13448
18         Dassault Falcon 8X            Please call   North America + Canada, United States - MD, Fo...  https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/...  Year 2016       S/N 406     Total Time 1627
19               Hawker 800XP   Price: USD $1,595,000  North America + Canada, United States - MD, Fo...  https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/...  Year 2002    S/N 258578    Total Time 10169
```

Comment: This is genius thanks so much however I got stuck when I added next_page pages commands above - can you please show me how to do the next pages as I've coded above & then output to csv file? much appreciated

Comment: Also Im using Chrome & not Mozilla/5.0 is this a problem?

Comment: One other thing if a field is not populated or doesn't have the element will this work? like my tag field

Comment: create a new question then I tell how you scrape next page

Comment: just managed to post a new question - Thanks          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979372/web-scrapping-beautifulsoup-next-page-parsing

Comment: ok I answer that question

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your `try`-`except` clauses are not allowing you to see and debug the errors in your script. If you remove them, you will see:

- `IndexError: list index out of range` in line 24. There are only two elements inside the list, and you are looking for the second one. Therefore, your line should be:

  `year = post.find_all('ul', class_ = 'fa-no-bullet clearfix')[1]`
- `KeyError: 2` in line 26. You are using `find()`, which returns a `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>` object, not a list. Here you want to use `find_all()` as you did in line 24. Same happens for line 28.

  However, instead of using this expression three times, you should rather store the result in a variable and use it later.
- `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` in line 31. There is a type, you wrote `_classs`.
- `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` in line 32. There is nothing wrong with your code. Instead, there are some entries in the webpage that don't have this element. You should check if the `find` method gave you any result.

  ```
  tag = post.find('div', class_ = 'list-viewing-date')
  if tag:
    tag = tag.text
  else:
    tag = None
  ```
- You don't have a way out of your `while` loop. You should catch whenever the script cannot find a new `next_page` and add a `break`.

After changing all this, it worked for me to scrape the first page. I used:

- `Python 3.9.7`
- `bs4 4.10.0`

It is very important that you state what versions of Python and the libraries you are using.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much for showing me the steps I went wrong, that really helps - I'm really new to this so it will take me a while to work through your notes.... I'm using Python 3.8.12 & probably the latest bs4