# Web Scraping & BeautifulSoup - Next Page parsing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm just learning web **scraping** & want to output the result of this website to a csv file https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets

but am struggling with parsing the next pages
here is my code (with help of Amen Aziz) which only gives me the 1st page
I'm using Chrome so not sure if it makes any difference
I'm running Python 3.8.12
Thank you in advance

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get('https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
postings = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'listing-item premium')
temp=[]
for post in postings:
    link = post.find('a', class_ = 'more-info').get('href')
    link_full = 'https://www.avbuyer.com'+ link
    plane = post.find('h2', class_ = 'item-title').text
    price = post.find('div', class_ = 'price').text
    location = post.find('div', class_ = 'list-item-location').text
    desc = post.find('div', class_ = 'list-item-para').text
    try:
        tag = post.find('div', class_ = 'list-viewing-date').text
    except:
        tag = 'N/A'
    updated = post.find('div', class_ = 'list-update').text
    t=post.find_all('div',class_='list-other-dtl')
    for i in t:
        data=[tup.text for tup in i.find_all('li')]
        years=data[0]
        s=data[1]
        total_time=data[2]

        temp.append([plane,price,location,years,s,total_time,desc,tag,updated,link_full])

df=pd.DataFrame(temp,columns=["plane","price","location","Year","S/N","Totaltime","Description","Tag","Last Updated","link"])


next_page = soup.find('a', {'rel':'next'}).get('href')
next_page_full = 'https://www.avbuyer.com'+next_page
next_page_full

url = next_page_full
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml') 

df.to_csv('/Users/xxx/avbuyer.csv')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
If you want `cvs file`  then you finish the line `print(df)` and use `df.to_csv("prod.csv")` I have written in code to get csv file

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
temp=[]
for page in range(1, 20):
    response = requests.get("https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/page-{page}".format(page=page),headers=headers,)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    postings = soup.find_all('div', class_='grid-x list-content')
    for post in postings:
        plane = post.find('h2', class_='item-title').text
        try:
            price = post.find('div', class_='price').text
        except:
            price=" "
        location = post.find('div', class_='list-item-location').text
        t=post.find_all('div',class_='list-other-dtl')
        for i in t:
            data=[tup.text for tup in i.find_all('li')]
            years=data[0]
            s=data[1]
            total_time=data[2]
            temp.append([plane,price,location,years,s,total_time])

df=pd.DataFrame(temp,columns=["plane","price","location","Years","S/N","Totaltime"])
print(df)
```

output:

```
                      plane         price  ...             S/N         Totaltime
0            Gulfstream G280     Make offer  ...        S/N 2007   Total Time 2528
1    Dassault Falcon 2000LXS     Make offer  ...         S/N 377     Total Time 33
2       Cirrus Vision SF50 G1  Please call   ...        S/N 0080    Total Time 615
3              Gulfstream IV     Make offer  ...        S/N 1148   Total Time 6425
4            Gulfstream G280     Make offer  ...        S/N 2072   Total Time 1918
..                        ...           ...  ...             ...               ...
342       Embraer Phenom 100       Now Sold  ...    S/N 50000035   Total Time 3417
343          Gulfstream G200       Now Sold  ...         S/N 152   Total Time 7209
344     Cessna Citation XLS+       Now Sold  ...           S/N -      Total Time -
345    Cessna Citation Ultra       Now Sold  ...    S/N 560-0393  Total Time 12947
346    Cessna Citation Excel       Now Sold  ...  S/N 560XL-5253   Total Time 4850
```

Comment: Thanks Amen but this only gives me the 1st page data, only 20 items same as before but there are 392 planes in total in the following pages which I need to scrape - I have mentioned in the title that I need multiple pages please & I tried it in my code above but it doesnt go to next page...

Comment: I have also noticed something interesting, in the postings = soup.find_all('div', class_='listing-item premium') I have to also add 'listing-item' as the premium postings have a box around them but not the normal postings so I have to include both 'listing-item premium' &  'listing-item' they have the same class -  the normal listings start in the middle of page 6 - really appreciate your help!

Comment: you try my code what output they gave you

Comment: Hi, your code gave me 80 rows only like you show above but there are a total of 399 planes _ I also noticed to get all the data I need to compound CSS selectors below but I dont know how?: `postings = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'listing-item premium')

postings = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'listing-item')

postings = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'listing-item wanted-item')`

Comment: I have modify the code check it now

Comment: you are a genius thank you so much! its much better however there are 394 planes & we managed to scrape 346 - from page 16 there are Wanted & Now Sold items that doesnt get scraped for some reason - Also whatever I do I cant get the "Wanted" to show in the table Im using ``` wanted = post.find('div', class_ = 'large-auto medium-auto cell').text``` but it doesnt work it should ideally show under Price column in the csv but Im happy for it to show anywhere - Thanks again for your help

Comment: and make another post than I  can help you

Comment: kindly accept the answer if you think it is helpful for you

Comment: thanks Amen here is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70002517/web-scrapping-beautifulsoup-multiple-pages

Comment: ok I answer that question