# Web Scraping & BeautifulSoup - Multiple Pages

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to this & just learning web scraping & want to output the result of this website to a csv file
https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets

but am struggling with parsing the full listings & I get only 346 from 395 planes - here is my code (with help of Amen Aziz) which its missing data from page 16 onwards as the Price will Change to Wanted & then Now Sold

Also whatever I do I cant get the "Wanted" to show in the table Im using

but it doesnt work it should ideally show under Price column in the csv but Im happy for it to show anywhere

I'm using Chrome & I'm running Python 3.8.12
Thank you in advance

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
temp=[]
for page in range(1, 20):
    response = requests.get("https://www.avbuyer.com/aircraft/private-jets/page-{page}".format(page=page),headers=headers,)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    postings = soup.find_all('div', class_='grid-x list-content')
    for post in postings:
            link = post.find('a').get('href')
            link_full = 'https://www.avbuyer.com'+ link
            plane = post.find('h2', class_ = 'item-title').text
            try:
                price = post.find('div', class_='price').text
            except:
                price="N/A"
            location = post.find('div', class_ = 'list-item-location').text
            desc = post.find('div', class_ = 'list-item-para').text.strip()
            try:
                tag = post.find('div', class_ = 'list-viewing-date').text
            except:
                tag = 'N/A'
            try:
                updated = post.find('div', class_ = 'list-update').text
            except:
                tag = 'N/A'    
            wanted = post.find('div', class_ = 'large-auto medium-auto cell').text
            try:
                client = post.find('p', class_ = 'client-name').text
            except:
                client = 'N/A'
            try:
                highlight = post.find('span', class_ = 'red-text').text
            except:
                highlight = 'N/A'
            t=post.find_all('div',class_='list-other-dtl')
            for i in t:
                data=[tup.text for tup in i.find_all('li')]
                years=data[0]
                sn=data[1]
                total_time=data[2]                
                temp.append([plane,price,location,years,sn,total_time,desc,tag,highlight,wanted,client,updated,link_full])

df=pd.DataFrame(temp,columns=["Plane","Price","location","Year","S/N","Total time","Description", "Tag", "Highlight","Wanted", "Client", "Updated", "Link"])
df.to_csv('/Users/xxx/avbuyer.csv')
```

Comment: can you share me pic what you can find for these line `wanted = post.find('div', class_ = 'large-auto medium-auto cell').text` it is difficult for find what you get

Comment: I dont know how to attach a pic here but the result I get for Wanted is ```Year 1997S/N 37Total Time 5333
                                ENGINES FRESHLY OVERHAULED LAST EXTERIOR PAINT - MARCH 2017 LAST INTERIOR REFURBISHMENT - JUNE 2017 ENGINES ENROLLED ON HONEYWELL CSP GOLD APU 
                            Updated 08 Nov 2021```.    I must have the wrong attribute for it but I dont know what else to use - you can see all Wanted ones on page 16 - Many thanks!!

Comment: brother your code is working they gave me `wanted table` in csv file

Comment: check the output in the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kLAx2cx3-Qv8fWrwbHQRGARS_hx6CuhK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: its under these 2 ```<div class="large-auto medium-auto cell"><div style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; margin-bottom: 10px;">WANTED</div><div class="list-item-para">
                                                            Gulfstream G200 - 9 or 10 pax preferred
                                                    </div></div>.              <div style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; margin-bottom: 10px;">WANTED</div>```

Comment: Bro I get the Wanted Column yes, but I want it to just say "Wanted" so I can filter instead of giving me all the repeated info

Comment: Also the Wanted Plane info wont show up in the search which are from page 16 - please can you give me this last help to extract these? many thanks!

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by adding below code to yours, Thanks again!   ```for post in postings:
            link = post.find('a').get('href')
            link_full = 'https://www.avbuyer.com'+ link
            plane = post.find('h2', class_ = 'item-title').text.strip()```

Comment: I thought I managed to get it correctly but didnt so I posted another question in case you have time to respond please - Thanks you Bro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70177836/web-scraping-beautifulsoup-multiple-pages-part-2